# Retrieving DateTime field from database gives me wrong time

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, datetime

I'm using this query to retrieve the fields I need between two users.

```js
var sql =  "SELECT DISTINCT u2.user_username as user ,u1.id_of_pois as id_of_pois , u2.Timestamp   
FROM pois_visit u1, pois_visit u2 
WHERE u1.user_username = ? AND u2.user_username = ? AND u1.id_of_pois = u2.id_of_pois AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, u1.Timestamp,u2.Timestamp) BETWEEN -2 AND 2"
```

**Datetime Field Called Timestamp**

[image]

As you can see my query is working perfectly. The only problem is I get the wrong time which is -3 hours from my database. I guess that's because my timezone is GMT +3
[image]

I want to retrieve the DateTime as it is in the database

Comment: What's the value of `u1.timestamp` and consider timezones, though they don't appear an issue.

Comment: Yes, the timezone of the server with the database is different than the timezone of the browser. You should explicitly add a timezone (e.g. the timezone of your server) to the timestamp strings in the SQL result.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I thought that too, but note the differences aren't in exact hours or even half hours-- I think something else is going on here.

Comment: Which values have difference other than 03:00:00 hours ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV Oh wow, you're right-- I didn't realize the second set of data was ordered differently from the first -- I should have checked the `id_of_pois` field to match, my bad

Comment: The value of u1.timestamp is the same with the rest. For example I doing my second row timestamp - the fifth row to check if they were in the same -+2 hours

Comment: @IVOGELOV how can add explicitly a timezone to my server? I tried to use AT TIMEZONE in my query but it was not working

Comment: Look into `SHOW VARIABLE` and `SET VARIABLE`. The variable in question is `system_time_zone`

Comment: If i do that then i will have problem with other timezones right? When I insert the Timestamp in my table I convert it to the right timezone per user.  Is it not possible when I extract it to take the same value as it is in the table without changing? Should I remove the system_time_zone?

Comment: MySQL does not store timezone in DATETIME or TIMESTAMP fields - so when doing SELECT you will have to convert DATETIME values into proper ISO-8601 format by yourself - e.g. if MySQL is set to UTC, then you can `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(u2.Timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%T+00:00") AS u_stamp`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its 100% accurate.
I fixed it by adding this code of line

```
timezone: 'utc'  //<-here this line was missing
```

In my app.js(nodejs) when initializing mysql connection